# How do I get all the commit SHA ID from a branch locally and on remote?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I am trying to get list of all the commit id's for a specific branch,

I am only aware that `git ls-remote <git-repo-url> | awk '{print $1}'` gives the latest commit sha of all the branches/heads.

my objective its to find if the local latest commit I get from `git rev-parse <branch_name>` is present in the list of all the commit's retrieved from the remote. if so I need to rebase, if the latest commit SHA on remote is present in the list of local commit sha then but is not my latest that means my branch locally have moved ahead and I do not need to do rebase but just push.

Comment: *"and I do not need to do rebase but just push."* -- `git rebase <branch1>` does not have any effect if `<branch1>` is an ancestor of the current branch. You can always rebase your local changes on top of the remote branch.

Comment: You can use [`git merge-base --is-ancestor <branch1> <branch2>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#git-merge-base---is-ancestor). It exits with code `0` if `<branch1>` is an ancestor of `<branch2>` and is much faster than your current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is determine whether your local branch has *diverged* from the remote branch, I think you're better served by `git-log` and the [triple-dot notation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_triple_dot). For example:

```
git log <local-branch>...<remote-branch> --oneline
```

will give you a list of commits that are in either `local-branch` or `remote-branch` but *not both*.

If you also add `--left-right`, you'll get an indication of which side the commit is on:

```
git log <local-branch>...<remote-branch> --oneline --left-right
```

where `<` means that the commit is *on the left but not the right*, while `>` means *on the right but not on the left*.

**Edit:** unless you're writing a script, in which case [`git-merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) with the [`--is-ancestor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#git-merge-base---is-ancestor) option suggested in [@axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834445/how-do-i-get-all-the-commit-sha-id-from-a-branch-locally-and-on-remote#comment88674444_50834445) is a better choice, since you can just check the exit code.

Comment: the stakeholder doesn't want to use the merge strategy, and this logic implementation is part of another script, I want to avoid the need to running the rebase command when we dont have to so just force push on the development branch. however for `git log <local-branch>...<remote-branch> --oneline`, `git fetch` must be executed beforehand.

Comment: `git-merge-base` is used to find a common parent between two or more commits, which is also what `git-rebase` does. As for your second comment, if you're going to compare a local branch with a remote one, you'll have to run `git-fetch` regardless.